# Spring Integration: Passing URL / Query Params programatically

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am invoking a external HTTP URL via Spring Integration, ***but*** my URL is completely hard-coded in the spring context file.

I want to:
- pass the Query Params from my program (i.e a=1&b=2&c=3)
- pass the URL itself from my progam (`i.e http://host/port/xyz`)

My Spring Integration Context file currently looks like this:

```
<int:gateway id="requestGateway" 
service-interface="com.bingo.RequestGateway"
default-request-channel="requestChannel"/>

<int:channel id="requestChannel"/>

<int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="requestChannel" 
url="http//host:port/xyz?a=1&b=2&c=3"
http-method="GET"
expected-response-type="java.lang.String"/>
```

The java code invoking this is:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                    "spring-integr.xml");
    RequestGateway requestGateway = context.getBean("requestGateway",
                    RequestGateway.class);
    String reply = requestGateway.sendMyRequest("");
    System.out.println("Replied with: " + reply);

}
```

Also:

```
public interface RequestGateway {    
    public String sendMyRequest(String request);
}
```

How can i pass the URL(`http://host:port/xyz`), and especially the params(a=1&b=2&c=3) via my program?

Answer (score 2):

Can you explain why don't you want to use **url-expression** for this purpose?
From Reference Manual:

> To specify the URL; you can use either the 'url' attribute or the 'url-expression' attribute. The 'url' is a simple string (with placedholders for URI variables, as described below); the 'url-expression' is a SpEL expression, with the Message as the root object, enabling dynamic urls. The url resulting from the expression evaluation can still have placeholders for URI variables.

[url-expression](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/2.2.5.RELEASE/reference/html/http.html#http-namespace)

Within this expression you can define an invocation of any method of any your bean.
In addition: since 3.0 there is introduce one more attribute - **encode-uri**, to allow disabling the encoding of the URI object before sending the request.

There is no need to do it from code. With SpEL it will be the opposite: from SI to your code, if it is available from Spring, of course.

```
<http:outbound-gateway url-expression="@myBean.getUrlFor(payload)" 
                  request-channel="requests">
     <uri-variable name="foo" expression="headers.bar"/>
</http:outbound-gateway>
```

Where your URL, as a result of method of that bean, may look like this:
`http://localhost/test2/{foo}`
Please, read the manual.

Comment: Artem Bilan> Can u please point me to an example/code of how to pass the url / url-expression / URI Variables from my java program to Spring Integration?

Comment: I added into my answer a sample